# Light weight OS

Tags: pi-2

Is there any light weight OS for RPi with GUI. All I have is an 8 GB micro SD card for boot so if I run any application on Raspbian OS such as chromium, it crashes

Comment: Your definition of "light weight" doesn't match mine - light weight means low use of RAM by the OS not low use of secondary storage. Raspbian Lite fits easily on a 4GB SDCard but isn't optimised for low RAM usage.

Comment: Which model of Pi are you using?

Comment: @CoderMike It's tagged `pi-2` 7 hours ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Raspbian Stretch with desktop** https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ works well on an 8GiB card - my installation (with lots of extra software) uses 5.3GiB

Comment: You're saving at least 1.3GB of SDCard space by not wasting it with NOOBS. Lots of my Raspberries don't use an SDCard. Three boot from USB sticks. Two boot from a hard drive. Two have a minimum sized SDCard with just the /boot folder and the root FS on a hard drive.

Comment: @Dougie I don't see how this is a Comment on my Answer. The only people who use [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) are beginners who follow the misleading Foundation "recommendation".

Comment: And like the OP they get short of space on Raspbian. It's time NOOBS was retired. Folks who want it for multiboot should use PINN