# Can't find /boot nor etc folder in downloaded NOOBS in SD Card. Need to add wpa_supplicant.conf file to connect to wifi on first boot in headless mode

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w, headless

I have downloaded NOOBS on an SD Card to install in my Raspberry Pi Zero W. I will boot it for the first time in headless mode (because I do not have access to an HDMI monitor) and for that i need to add the wpa_supplicant.conf file with wifi details and also need to enable SSH. However, from what I have read so far on doing this, I shall have to add this file to /boot directory. Can't find it. Have I made any mistakes in understanding the process? Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

You CAN NOT setup [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) without a monitor and keyboard.

You can't find the boot directory - because it doesn't exist until you setup an OS.

Just install Raspbian - it is easier (and doesn't waste space)