# Using NOOBS pro and con?

Tags: raspbian, noobs

NOOBS seems like it would save time for beginner.  Is there any con of using it versus installing from a regular image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want the dual boot capability NOOBS is "wasting" 1.3GB of the available space on your SDCard for zero benefit.

NOOBS has been forked to PINN - see https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=142574 which has some wonderful extras (like password reset and filesystem checking). If you want dual boot use PINN.

For a user who just wants plain Raspbian - you should use a plain download and Etcher to write your SDCard.

Comment: Your answer is duplicate to that from *Milliways* [Should I install NOOBS or Raspbian?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92068/should-i-install-noobs-or-raspbian). You should better flag the question as duplicate.