# ssh not working after creation ssh file

Tags: ssh, headless

I am trying to setup my raspberry pi headless. I understand that we can create a file by name ssh in the boot partition (the one that is accessible on windows) to gets this working. I have connected the raspberry pi to my home router ethernet port and obtained its DHCP IP from the router.

However, even after creating the ssh file (tried ssh, ssh.txt and SSH) I still get connection refused.

Does this method still work?
I am using NOOBS
Offline and network install
Version:3.0.1
Release date:2019-04-08

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this works for NOOBS (it probably would if you put in the Raspbian boot partition, but I believe  Windows doesn't show this).

Why are you using [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697)
 - this only works with a Screen & keyboard - which are needed to setup Raspbian (or any OS on NOOBS) for the 1st time?

If you want headless install [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/)

Comment: @dip please flag this answer as accepted if this is the solution to the problem.