# Cannot get installed system to output component video, but NOOBS can

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, noobs, composite-video

Background: Pi 3 B+ connected to an old tube TV with front composite video connection.

I've installed NOOBS on a 32GB microSD card, and am able to successfully boot it, using the keyboard `4` key (NTSC) to display the graphical installer.  After the install finishes and the Pi boots, **I can no longer get any video to display**.

I have set `sdtv_mode=0` and `hdmi_ignore_hotplug=0` in the `config.txt` on the /boot partition of the SD card.

Comment: You are unlikely to get help on [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) very few use it. /boot  is ambiguous, the Raspbian boot partition is only mounted when it boots; NOOBS has its own.

Comment: @Milliways okay, that piece of info might be just what I needed to progress further.  I'm going to try a bare Raspbian install and see where that gets me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the forum topic posted [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=243855), the newest version of Raspbian (Buster) had an option added to support the Pi 4 that broke component video out.  Downgrading my Raspbian version and using a bare install solved this issue for me.