# Stopping a new Raspbian Stretch install from upgrading to Buster

Tags: raspbian-stretch, noobs, raspbian-buster

I am a Linux user but a bit of a noob with respect to the Pi. I have a Pi that was running Raspbian Stretch with [GassistPi](https://github.com/shivasiddharth/GassistPi) as a tinkering tool and a sort of attraction, to tinkering, for my kids.  However, I broke the SD card in an accident, and had to get a new one.

Now, when I reinstall Stretch from the copy of NOOBS I had bought, it automatically upgrades itself to Buster.  But GassistPi is not yet [able to run on Buster](https://github.com/shivasiddharth/GassistPi/issues/931).  In some of the issue comments in this and linked issues, there are references to running Raspbian Stretch.  Is there a way I can install Stretch without the auto-upgrade to Buster?  Is this a problem because of the scripts in NOOBS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raspbian will NEVER upgrade to a different OS.

NOOBS, on the other hand always installs the latest version (or the copy included with NOOBS) - I might add that very few experienced users of this site use [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) .

If you don't have a backup, you can install any released version of Raspbian.

Pick one from https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/

AFAIK 2019-04-09 23:46 is the latest Stretch release.