# Raspberry pi 3 A+

Tags: performance

The Raspberry Pi 3 A+ ,I think is memory-constrained,in that Chromium does not work well. I wanted to code Scratch 3 on it as Scratch 2 is only available offline. Using the web seems off limits and so does Sonic Pi even offline. Thonny for Python is usable offline . Is there any way around this issue?. Would using some type of adaptor work e.g. Pimorono. Also, I presume it is more suited to hardware projects similar to Pi zero projects,am I right? I downloaded Raspbian via Noobs onto 16 Gb micro-sd card initially.

Comment: Why don't you buy a Pi4 4GB?

Comment: Because I just got this one and I presume it will work for some purpose

Comment: It will work fine for anything that does not require lots of memory. Looks like you've had loads of suggestions on the Pi forum https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=254791

Comment: Ahh! I know but it all sounds gobbledygook. I am amazed someone can track that!

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [Foundation documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/scratch-3-desktop-for-raspbian-on-raspberry-pi/) you will see that Scratch 3 **ONLY** works on a Pi4 (or earlier model with 1GB RAM, but operation is marginal).

The Pi3A+ has the same memory 500MB as the earlier single CPU Pi models with a 4 core processor. It is an extremely capable machine - the only limitation is the number of simultaneous tasks.

You can certainly install Scratch 2 (which should be included in the full download).

**DO NOT** use [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697), install Raspbian.