# Pi does not find NOOBS files

Tags: pi-3b+

My Raspberry Pi is not finding the NOOBS files. I have tried to make the SD card bootable, but it did not get me as far as if I just unzipped NOOBS on to the Sd card. The screen is blank. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions for *installing* NOOBS exactly? Seems the handful of people that use NOOBS have no trouble installing it - https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md

Comment: "Any suggestions?" YES don't install [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) install Raspbian.

Comment: How exactly did you try to make the SC card bootable? I see no such step in the installation document.

Comment: 1. I finally got it working. 2. My Dad and I saw something on the internet to make the card bootable while using terminial. I used balena etcher. before, I did not know how to install it.