# Stuck on rainbow screen with my rp4b

Tags: pi-4

It remains stuck on the rainbow screen, and I don't know what to do. I've followed all the steps and I'm still stuck on the rainbow screen. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried un-plugging the Pi and plugging it back in again?
Have you installed Raspbian successfully or is this screen before you can even install that?

Comment: What power supply are you using? Did you install Raspbian directly using Etcher or via Noobs?

Comment: 5V-2A power supply and via NOOBS

Comment: @Legendus I've tried that as well. And I've installed Raspbian via NOOBS. I also formatted my SD Card to FAT instead of NTFS. Still not working.

Comment: Recommended power supply is 5.1V 3A https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/type-c-power-supply/ However try flashing 'Raspbian with Desktop' direct to sd card with Etcher https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Comment: What else is connected to the Pi-4 by USB?

Comment: It is not a power issue.  It's a partially corrupted, improperly prepared, or just plain defective SD card.

Answer (score 0):

1. See [Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558) follow the diagnostics and post any findings. If you get as far as the rainbow screen see [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)
2. Do **NOT** install [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) install [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md).
3. Ignore all the uninformed rubbish about power supplies, unless you see the power warning.

Comment: Ignoring the Raspberry Pi foundations recommended power requirements is bad advise particularly for new users.

Comment: @CoderMike The symptoms described by the OP **DO NOT** indicate power problems, so advice to check power is misleading. The Foundation [recommendations](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs) indicate the Pi4 will run on 600mA.