# Raspberry Pi B+ doesn't boot after upgrading the os

Tags: raspbian, boot

Today I upgraded the Raspbian os from version Stretch to Buster with

```
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now I can't boot Raspbian. Only a black screen appears. 
When I try to load the different os, like LibreELEC or Windows IoT, it starts properly.

Can somebody help me with how to slow this problem?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't root? || Put an rj45 cable to the LAN port, is it start the lighting? Maybe it just can load data to screen/HDMI.

Comment: It start lighting, but nothing happens. It was working fine before the upgrade. I tryed 2 different screens, but still nothing...

Comment: Try to connect to the RPi by SSH. Ping the IP from another host. What's the result?

Comment: You appear to be using [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697)
If so, your options are limited, as NOOBS only option is to reinstall all OS.

Comment: Do you upgrade from Raspbian Stretch to Raspbian Buster?

Comment: @Ingo Yes, I do.