# Accidently disabled overscan on pi 4b

Tags: recovery

Stupid me. I accidentally disabled overscan and it won't show anything after normal post, it shows the rainbow-colored screen, then shifts for recovery then after what nothing.
I don't want to lose any files and documents, I know it wasn't the wisest idea to not back up or use the pi as a primary file hold. Is there any way I can remedy this?

Comment: Press SHIFT. The NOOBS recovery has a config.txt editor so you can undo your broken changes.

Comment: *"I don't want to lose any files and documents"* -> They're probably still there and accessible from any computer that can read an `ext4` filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

With the information supplied it is difficult to suggest any answer.

If you "don't want to lose any files and documents" **DO NOTHING** with the SD Card.
Do a fresh installation - preferably Raspbian NOT [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697)

You can then mount the SD Card in a reader on the Pi and recover your files.
Ask another question if you need help with this.