# Can I run latest NOOBS on a Pi 2?

Tags: pi-2, noobs

Can i run the current version of NOOBS on a Raspberry Pi-2?  I have tried but it will not boot up.

Comment: NOOBS isn't an operating system. It's an installer for operating systems like Raspbian. NOOBS 3.2.1 should boot up OK on every model of Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) on any model Pi.

Why you would WANT to rather than installing Raspbian given its disadvantages is unclear.

PS it is unlikely any of the experienced users on this site have actually tried it.