# Can't Forget SSID, Even after rm from wpa_supplicant

Tags: wifi, pi-4, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to forget an SSID from a new Raspberry Pi 4. I need to get it connected to a hidden network in our house, but it grabbed a public guest network first by default, and now I can't get it to go away. I turn off the wifi, edit /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf (yes, as sudo) to remove the existing network reference. Save it, close it, re-open it to confirm that the network has been removed. Turn on wifi, it immediately grabs the same wifi name and reinserts the entry back into wpa_supplicant.

If I erase bad_public from wpa_supplicant and put in good_hidden SSID, it still won't grab it--defaults to bad_public and inserts the record. It sure seems like there's some *other* place where the record is getting cached and it keeps reconnecting. Thanks for your help.

EDIT to add: Running Raspbian from NOOBS 3.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) has to access networking and has its own mechanism, independent of Raspbian.

Normally it re-configures Raspbian on installation. It may be overwriting the Raspbian settings.

Unfortunately you are unlikely to get help on NOOBS on this site because most experienced users don't use it.

I suggest you reboot the the NOOBS setup and try disabling there.

PS reading a file after changing it DOES NOT prove it has been written to the SD Card - it may be cached, but should be written if properly shutdown.

Comment: basically, NOOBS causes more issues (for newbies) than it solves

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the out-of-the-box NOOBS card with a pure Raspbian install. Worked just fine. Yay Raspbian, Boo NOOBS!