# SD Card Resize on 32gb SD Card Raspberry Pi

Tags: sd-card, partition, root, file, resize

I have a 32gb SD card in my Raspberry Pi. I'd like to make use of all the space, please can someone tell me how to resize?

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 29.7 GiB, 31914983424 bytes, 62333952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0004b03e

Device         Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1         8192  4615234  4607043  2.2G  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      4615235 30375935 25760701 12.3G  5 Extended
/dev/mmcblk0p5      4620288  4685821    65534   32M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p6      4685824  5210109   524286  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p7      5210112 30375935 25165824   12G 83 Linux
```

Comment: What operating system do you use? Or do you use NOOBS?

Comment: It was originally installed with NOOBS

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be an extended partition which is only using 12.5GB.

It is unclear how you managed to get this, probably by copying a smaller SD Card.

This can be fixed on a Linux computer, it is probably possible to fix it on the Pi itself, but this requires some expertise and involves some risk.

Your best bet is to do a fresh install of *Raspberry Pi OS* (on a new Card) and copy your data.

It is inadvisable to use [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) - this is difficult to maintain, and if you had used *Raspberry Pi OS* resizing the partition is simple.