# Pi wont boot: Failed to start Load Kernel Module

Tags: boot-issues, noobs, partition

In short, the Pi just stopped booting.
I looked at the boot screen, which displayes FAILED messages:

> Failed to start Load Kernel Module

and keeps rebooting after

> A start job is running for dev-mmcblk0p6

I can't even enter commands at this point.
I checked how the SD Card looks in an Linux File Reader in Linux.
Now, I've aquired enough skills to realize that this isn't how its supposed to be

[image: List of partitions]

The partitioning seems... off. By a lot.
Is there anything I can do to restore the Pi?

Comment: looks like a standard NOOBS layout ... I'm kidding, never seen a noobs disk in my life, but I know it loves partitioning the life out of a disk

Comment: In your other system run `sudo umount /dev/sdb6; sudo fsck -f -y /dev/sdb6; sudo eject /dev/sdb` [note I'm assuming it appears as /dev/sdb when you insert the USB reader]. Then try again in your RPi. If it still doesn't work write RaspiOS32 to another SDCard then rescue data & programs from the original card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The illegible image is probably a [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) installation.

The error indicates something on partition 6 is not running.

This is probably caused by some file which has become corrupt.

If you have a backup you could try restoring from this.

Otherwise you should do a fresh installation - it is also advisable to use a new SD Card; these do wear out, and you should be able to recover your files from the old SD Card.

It is preferable to install *Raspberry Pi OS* rather than [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697), and if you **REALLY** need multiple OS on the one card use [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md)

Comment: After some further investigation, it seems like the the device `dev-mmcblk0p6` was located on a corrupted block. Probably due to power outage. I tried a lot of stuff, but it seems like the data is gone and this is the reason the Pi doesn't boot anymore. Thanks for your advice!