# Can't find boot partition on SD card

Tags: noobs

I just got a Raspberry Pi yesterday to run some Python automation scripts on it.

I downloaded the zip file of NOOBS, extracted it, and placed all the contains (including overlays, os, defaults) in my micro SD card. Since I'm connecting to the Pi through Ethernet, I have to create an SSH file in the boot partition... However, I have no idea where the boot partition is... The only thing I can see are the contents I already placed in my SD card (overlays, os, defaults, etc). Help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I think most of us here recommend people use a plain Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS image instead of NOOBS -- despite the labelling the latter seems to confuse newcomers more than anything else, and 98% of them will only use it to load Raspbian anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making partition is necessary and you must do it with specified software. Copying from a zip file won't work in this case. After you finish partitioning you will find the boot partition(if you are using windows and used the etcher software for partitioning). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since RPF changed the default to have SSH disabled, you cannot set Raspbian up with SSH via NOOBS simply.

The only way to get this to work requires your Mac or PC to be able to recognise all partitions on the card and then:

1. Install Raspbian via NOOBS
2. Insert the card back in your machine
3. Identify /boot partition
4. Add the SSH file into this

Not the simplest way to say the least and oddly enough NOOBS had SSH added back in 2015 so you could run that bit headless!

Unfortunately even the new imager has not enabled SSH start up and its addition has been [actively rejected](https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-imager/issues/73) recently

It is a lot simpler to either use a keyboard and monitor at first boot OR to set Raspbian up directly on the SD.

Unfortunately, [Berryboot](https://berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) also does not support this BUT it’s beginning to allow extra config options such as overscan etc.

**tl;dr**
Forget NOOBS - install Raspbian direct to the card.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot setup [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) without a screen and keyboard.

You can't find the `boot` partition because it doesn't exist until you have setup [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) - in which case you might as well enable `ssh` via raspi-config. (Indeed you can't access it on Windows, even then.)

If you only want to run the officially supported *Raspberry Pi OS* there is no benefit is using NOOBS and it makes subsequent support more difficult.