# Unable to upgrade my model 2B Pi running Jessie

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, software-installation

I am trying to update all of the software on my model b pi.

I have cleared as much space as possible - then did df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       6.0G  5.2G  450M  93% /
devtmpfs        427M     0  427M   0% /dev
tmpfs           432M     0  432M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           432M   12M  420M   3% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           432M     0  432M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p6   63M   20M   43M  32% /boot
tmpfs            87M     0   87M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/mmcblk0p5   30M  398K   28M   2% /media/pi/SETTINGS2
```

The sudo apt full-upgrade command told me it needed this much space:

```
After this operation, 223 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

But the unpacking process failed with:

```
Unpacking libreoffice-calc (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-core_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-core (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
dpkg:../../src/unpack.c:123:deb_reassemble: internal error: unexpected exit status 11 from dpkg-split
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly
```

Or should I change OS to stretch (does that work on model b?
I have no legacy software on my pi - clean start would not be a hardship.
Very grateful for any ideas.

Comment: I've successfully updated wheezy => jessie, and jessie => stretch and stretch => buster over the years on my original piB - so, upgrading by ONE version definitely works ... however, I manually prepared things like a bigger boot partition (256MB) before doing so - this doesn't address your issue though, I think the fact that you have so little space is going to be an issue .... also, it's clear your original install was NOOBS - and NOOBS is poorly named, since you need to be anything but a NOOB to fix the issues it invariably causes

Comment: If you are going to do a re-install, it would probably be worthwhile to splurge on a 16GB (!!) card.

Answer (score 4):

You wrote

> clean start would not be a hardship.

So I strongly recommend to do it. There are some important reasons to do it, because it isn't worth the effort to fix your installation:

1. Jessie is deprecated since years and out of any support since 2020-01-01. Its repository is archived.
2. Seems you have installed **NOOBS** but only using **Raspbian**. NOOBS is a waste of storage. As far as I know it needs more than 1 GB of space. Most of us does not use it because it is also error prone.
3. Just install the [Raspberry Pi OS version Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/) direct from its image. This will save storage. And yes, it will also run on your RPi 2B.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be running [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697)
(one of the Foundation's worst ideas).

This is **NOT** upgradable - even a "fresh install" will fail.

Even if you had directly installed Raspbian, the Foundation advice is to do a fresh install of Buster. (It is possible for expert users to upgrade but this actually takes longer than a fresh install. Skipping versions just makes this more difficult.)

Install [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/) using one of the [recommended methods](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md)