# REINSTALL THE NOOBS to another OS

Tags: noobs

I just installed the Raspian with Noobs and run perfectly the Debian raspian. But the problem start when i did it again and run the raspberry to install other OS. Q: How do i install other OS after install raspian with Noobs? I tried the some images of each OS( Ubuntu, Retro pie, OSMC,..) but had no effects

Comment: This can't be done. Once you've completed the first NOOBS boot up nothing can change without reformatting the SDCard and starting again. It is a one-shot process.

Answer (score 1):

As Dougie has said you can't. (Although it may have changed in the 7 years since I was deluded enough to try it.)

[NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) is a disaster - even the Foundation doesn't push it any more.

If you want multiple OS I suggest you try  [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md) instead, but most of us use one OS per SD Card.