# How to delete SMB shortcuts/links from the desktop?

Tags: filesystem, samba

I used File Manager to browse some files on my NAS:

`//BACKUP/Files`

When I did so, a shortcut (or symlink) was automatically placed on my desktop.

Now I cannot delete this item. When I attempt to do so, File Manager wants to delete the files on the NAS instead of the item on my desktop.

How can I remove this shortcut/link from the desktop?

---

EDIT

Here's my `ls` output:

```
pi@OFFSITE:~/Desktop $ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 202 Jul 19 18:46 ExternalUSB.desktop
```

---

EDIT

Here's my `mount` output:

```
pi@OFFSITE:~/Desktop $ mount
/dev/mmcblk0p7 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=341236k,nr_inodes=85309,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=31,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/mmcblk0p6 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/elements type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=94664k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

---

EDIT

Here's my `lsblk` output:

```
pi@OFFSITE:~/Desktop $ lsblk --fs
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL    UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                             
└─sda1      ntfs            D6986D4D986D2CE5                        7.9T    14% /mnt/elements
mmcblk0                                                                         
├─mmcblk0p1 vfat   RECOVERY 9016-4EF8                                           
├─mmcblk0p2                                                                     
├─mmcblk0p5 ext4   SETTINGS 2fe2ad4a-81c1-430b-ad2a-a7fd4ed14971                
├─mmcblk0p6 vfat   boot     9AD7-B5BD                               213M    15% /boot
└─mmcblk0p7 ext4   root     e0c17230-abcf-45fc-abbe-fe49a78a61b1     18G    28% /
```

---

EDIT

Note that the mounted drive seen above (`sda/sd1`), as well as the desktop shortcut pointing to it (`ExternalUSB.desktop`), are unrelated to this issue. The object that was automatically added to the desktop when I connected to my NAS so far hasn't shown up in any terminal command I've issued.

---

Comment: Is this a Windows desktop? If so, why are you asking this question here - on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: This is on an RPi4.

Comment: OK - the back-slashes confused me.

Comment: Ah, good point. I fixed that. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Are you certain this is a symlink? I.e. if you run `ls -l` on your desktop folder, you see the letter `l` (ell) as the first character of this?

Comment: I am not. In fact, I'm not sure *what* it is. I've added my `ls` output to the question.

Comment: It's not a link. It appears you have `mount`ed this drive - that's why File Mgr is trying to erase files.

Comment: Aha. Then I should be able to simply unmount it. I'll look into how to do that.

Comment: `lsblk --fs` will show you what you need to know

Comment: Hmm...  `lsblk` doesn't show anything, nor does `mount`. I've added those outputs as well.

Comment: `sudo umount /mnt/elements`? I've no idea how this came to be called `//BACKUP/files` - do you?

Comment: Oh... the `elements` mount is my USB drive, currently receiving a 4TB file. So I won't want to interrupt that. My nomenclature for `//BACKUP/Files` is simply the UNC path to the share on my NAS. The actual object on the desktop is named `files on backup.local`.

Comment: `umount //Backup/Files`, then [read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41757/how-to-remove-mounted-locations-that-have-been-added-using-the-mount-command)

Comment: This is getting stranger and stranger. `umount: //Backup/Files: No such file or directory | umount: //Backup/files: No such file or directory | umount: //backup.local/Files: No such file or directory | umount: //backup/Files: No such file or directory | umount: //backup/files: No such file or directory`

Comment: I don't think it's a `mount`ed share. It doesn't show up in the `mount` command output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110831/discussion-between-intexx-and-seamus).

Comment: This question is unclear. You appear to be using NOOBS and a NTFS disk both BAD ideas.

Comment: Is there a better alternative to NOOBS? I'm interested. As far as NTFS, I did weigh my options before making that decision. As this whole configuration exists as a backup target for my Windows VMs, I need to be able to restore into that environment. I need to be able to plug the USB drive into a Windows machine and proceed from there. However, I'm willing to consider alternative suggestions that meet this base requirement. | @Milliways

Comment: Also, could you elaborate a bit on what problems I might encounter with NOOBS/NTFS. Thanks. | @Milliways

Comment: Do not put details in Comments - edit your question. All these will disappear into chat

Comment: Sure, I'm game... but these details (NOOBS/NTFS) are off-topic for the question. Are you certain? | @Milliways

Comment: Also, I'm at a loss as to how I can make the question clearer. I described what I did, and what the unwanted outcome was. I described how I tried to rectify the problem and the result of that attempt. Could you suggest how I might edit the question to make it clearer? | @Milliways

Answer (score 1):

See my analysis of [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697).
Suffice it to say none of the experienced users use it.

NTFS on Raspbian is read-only by default, although there is a R/W module that can be installed. The Linux implementation of NTFS (which is reverse engineered because it is proprietary) lacks journalling.

I must admit I haven't used NTFS for years (except to read portable drives) but those who do report slow access.

NOTE The partition is **MOUNTED** on `/mnt/elements` as shown by:-

```
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/elements type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

Thus questions about NAS are unclear.

Incidentally `findmnt` produces a more usable output.

Comment: *"NOOBS"* Very good, thank you. I'll have a close look at that. The mounted USB drive is completely separate from the original question. The only reason I decided to include it here in the `ls`, `mount`, and `lsblk` outputs was to demonstrate that the desktop object apparently linked to my NAS somehow (the object that I'm trying to delete) isn't a mounted drive/partition/share, nor is it a symlink. The `//BACKUP/Files` UNC path points to my NAS.

Comment: I added a brief statement for clarity. Does that help?

Comment: Also: I didn't realize the RPi OS was available in anything other than NOOBS. Thanks for the tip. I'll use the ISO for all future installs.

Comment: FYI the NTFS partition was formatted by Windows, so journaling is enabled (that said, RPi probably can't write to it, as you indicate). My requirement to be able to plug the drive into a Windows machine and hit the ground running with a restore operation is a pretty heady one. Correct me please, but I don't think we're going to meet that with ext4 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just ejected the folder from the file manager. Now it is gone