# Can I run NOOBS directly off of a Chromebook?

Tags: noobs, chrome-os

I have a good 64-bit chromebook and 16GB SD card. I want to use multiple noobs OSs, but my Pi was destroyed by my dog. Is this possible without buying a new Pi?

Comment: You can't "run" [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) on anything, because it is an OS installer/boot manager - even then it only works on a Pi.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot use NOOBS or any Raspberry Pi OS directly on a chromebook.

You need to buy a new Pi and keep it away from your dog!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. No, it is not easy.

First, you need to get `qemu` working. I have never tried it on a chromebook, but https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/running-virtual-machines-on-your-chromebook suggests that it can be done.

Next step is to get your Pi image working under Qemu. https://azeria-labs.com/emulate-raspberry-pi-with-qemu/ gives a hint on how to do that. I have actually got this part working under Linux, but if you have qemu on your chromebook, it should work there too.

The result is somewhat disappointing in speed, but it functionally works.

Comment: I understand the full Pi OS would be slow, but I use NOOBS for Lakka (emulation) & LibreElec (media). ould those be of better performance since they are slim?

Comment: Much of the slowness comes from the fact that you are running an emulation of an ARM processor on an x86. So perhaps it may be a bit faster, but do not expect it to run at a speed comparable to the real thing.

Comment: My chromebook is a 64bit OS actually. Really good specs.

Comment: Would that help or is it purely the arm board that slows it down?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the questions that you ask make it clear that you have very little experience with emulation. That would make it also extremely hard to get this working. My advice is: buy a new Pi (for example a zero).