# Raspberry Pi Black Screen

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-4

I just got a new raspberry pi 4 model B.
I used it twice and it was working perfectly fine.
But on the third time, when I tried to turn it one, I have the rainbow screen then the screen which says "for recovery hold key shift" (or something like this) and then I have a black screen.
I don't understand because I have a new hdmi cable which came with the raspberry pi (I tried two different cables) and then I have as input a mouse and a keyboard.
I tried with two different screens as well.

What can the problem be ?
Please help me

Comment: This is a [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) prompt. Very few actually use NOOBS, which just makes life harder and you are unlikely to get help. Install *Raspberry Pi OS*

Comment: Ditto Milliways -- NOOBs is more, not less hassle than plain Raspbian/Rpi OS.  It sounds like the data on the card has been corrupted (remember: You must shut the system down properly before you pull the plug), so you might as well just re-install (not NOOBs!).