# Samsung 64GB EVO Select U1 Failing SD Card Speed Test

Tags: sd-card, performance

I have a 64 GB EVO Select U1 SD Card ([link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XWN9Q99)). I ran the Raspberry Pi Diagnostics SD Card Speed test on it. The card always fails the random write test by a large margin (the target speed for this test is 500 IOPS. The test reports usually around 100 IOPS for random writes, and sometimes reports as low as 60 IOPS), and it sometimes fails the sequential write test.

Looking at [publicly available performance results that include the EVO Plus](https://www.tomshardware.com/best-picks/raspberry-pi-microsd-cards), the failure seems unexpected. ([Discussions online](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyNote8/comments/826ahx/micro_sd_card_difference_256gb_evo_plus_vs_evo/) suggest that it is reasonable to expect similar performance from the EVO Plus and Select cards.)

I see that the log with the test results says that sequential write performance may degrade as the SD card is used, and that reformatting it might help. I had been using this card on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+, and I recently installed <s>NOOBS</s> Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) on the card using the Raspberry Pi Imager to use it on my new Raspberry Pi 4. I assume that using the Imager reformatted the card, but I can't confirm this from research for sure.

Do you have any suggestions about why the SD card might be failing the test?

Comment: This makes no sense. Why ANYONE would want to inflict [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) on a Pi eludes me. You **CAN'T** install it with Raspberry Pi Imager and it won't reformat the SD Card (again this is pointless).

Comment: *Do you have any suggestions about why the SD card might be failing the test?* - perhaps,  since you've been using this SD card on a Pi3B+, this has resulted in *sequential write performance may degrade as the SD card is used* - seems the answer to your question is in your question

Comment: @Milliways - couldn't noobs be installed using the "Custom image" option in raspberry pi imager? I've never tried, having never understood the reason for noobs

Comment: @JaromandaX NOOBS is not an image; it's a collection of files which need to be copied.

Comment: oh, lesson learned @Milliways

Comment: The reason I was uncertain about whether reformatting would help is because the message in the test log says that reformatting might help *sequential* write performance. The sequential write test almost always passes. The *random* write performance test always fails.