# Does this "NOOBS" installer contain a simple option to encrypt the system disk?

Tags: raspbian, noobs, encryption

When "burning" one of these to the memory card, the resulting Raspberry Pi OS installation is installed without encryption: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/

I've found out the hard and slow way that it's impossible to encrypt the disk after the "installation" ("burning" the image to the flash card).

Therefore, I'm considering instead using the installer approach: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/

However, since this means setting up a monitor and keyboard and everything, I can't test it easily.

None of the videos show anything useful, such as going through what "NOOBS" actually looks like and what options it presents. The text description mentions nothing about encryption.

Does this "NOOBS" installer allow me to select for it to encrypt the disk so that it requires a password input on every boot and nobody can steal my RPI and/or its flash card and read the contents of my OS/data?

Comment: 1.) [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479)  2.) https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/home 
 3.) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=LUKS

Comment: None of us use [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697)
 let alone trying to fiddle with encryption using it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use NOOBS to install Raspberry Pi OS It's one more thing to worry about when you're troubleshooting an installation. Just use the [Raspberry Pi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) or something like Etcher. For Encrypting the OS the Offical Raspberry Pi forum has a [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=219867) with instructions on how to do this. The OP used [LUKS](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/) and created a [script](https://github.com/styper/Luks-Encrypt-Raspbian-Stretch) you could use.