# Error saving /etc/dhcpcd.conf The dhcpcd configuration file is not writeable (Raspberrypi 3b+)

Tags: raspbian

If I put the cursor over the Wi-Fi icon, it says 'No wireless interface found'.

Also, if I press Wireless & Wired Network Settings, the error saving /etc/dhcpcd.conf notification appears.
[image: the error notification]

The picture below is the result of command `sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf`.
[image: /etc/dhcpcd.conf]

And the picture below is the result of command `sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`
[image: /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf]

I don't know what's the problem.
I tried all the ways to solve problems similar to mine on the Internet, but I can't solve this issue.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: what is the output of `mount | grep ext4`

Comment: You have obviously modified `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` which is presumably the cause of your problem. **DO NOT** paste pictures paste TEXT. **NOTE** there is ABSOLUTELY no point in trying to obscure private IP addresses.

Comment: First execute these commands: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd.service`. Then do these commands, [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/117415/edit) your question and paste its **text** output to it: `ls -l /etc/dhcpcd.conf` and `systemctl status dhcpcd.service`. Don't use screenshots as images!

Comment: @JaromandaX the output is '/dev/mmcblk07 on / type ext4 (rw, noatime)'

Comment: @Ingo I did these commands. And I want to paste the text output, but  I can't copy and paste the text here from the laptop connected to the Raspberrypie to my laptop. It's not connected to each other. What do I do? I just have to write down the output?

Comment: oh ... are you using NOOBS?

Comment: @JaromandaX  Yes, I am.. Is this a problem..?

Comment: no, but noobs causes more issues than it solves :p (not this one though, your root is mounted read-write, so that's not going to be the problem)

Comment: @Milliways  I want to copy and paste the text output, but I can't copy and paste the text here from the laptop connected to the Raspberrypie to my laptop. It's not connected to each other. What do I do? I just have to write down the output?

Comment: @JaromandaX Then it doesn't seem like a problem, does it?

Comment: None of the comments or your responses have addressed the fact that you have fiddled with  `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` (for whatever reason) which you have not explained. Without this any further comment is futile.

Comment: @Moon you could just open this question here and sign in and edit the question on the RPi. Just copy (I think it's CTRL + SHIFT + C instead, but someone please correct me if I'm wrong) and paste into here.

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino I thought the wifi connection wasn't working, so I thought internet connection would not work. but, this link will be open, right? Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Ah true, did not think that through. You gonna have to manually type it out or use a console cable to access the Pi

Comment: @Moon Please don't type it out. It's too much and annoying. Take a picture.

Answer (score 0):

You have obviously modified `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` which is presumably the cause of your problem; either the contents are corrupt or the permissions wrong.

As you have not explained what you did or shown the contents or permissions and obscured relevant details it is difficult to make any concrete suggestions.

You should restore `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to its default. (It is best practice to ALWAYS make a backup copy of systems files before modifying them.)

If you can not do this, either restore from your backup or do a fresh installation - preferably **NOT using NOOBS**

[NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) contains instructions for installation.

Judging from the fragments that are visible, you appear to have attempted to set a Static IP Address. This is not recommended in most cases, but if you want to
[How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697) explains alternatives and instructions on how to do it properly.

[How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) is a more general guide to configuring Raspbian networking.

PS It is recommended that when editing system files you use `sudoedit` rather than `sudo nano`.