# How NOOBS OS boots? (in recovery mode)

Tags: raspbian, noobs, recovery

I am trying to implement something which requires me to learn this:-
**How Raspberry pi NOOBS OS boots in recovery mode while holding SHIFT key?**

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I have found out after I checked out noobs code as well as reverse engineering it.

For booting `recovery.efi` is loaded by bootloader. From here kernel is loaded from `recovery.img` or some other one for your pi.

Now kernel will load `recovery.rfs` to the ram. `recovery.cmdline` contains ram0 as root this means kernel will call `sbin/init` from ramdisk.

Now init will call `/usr/bin/recovery` (an ELF 32bit arm program) its source code is in noobs git.

Upon reading `main.cpp` what I felt is that, after it detects recovery partition, it calls bootmenu function. This function once fixed the partition to boot to, will use SYS_reboot system call to reboot to the new OS.

Now I don't know how it does not invoke the bootloader but I know someone with  greater understanding than me will post another how it does not literally reboot.

Also note that `recovery.elf` is start.elf which will read `autoboot.txt` to set boot partition to boot.

[edit]
I have successfully booted multiple os with this idea.
Below given is a system call can be invoked with c or cpp.
`syscall(SYS_reboot, LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC1, LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2, LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART2, "1");`
Here /dev/mmcblk0p1 will be taken as the boot partition. You can replace that with 2 for /dev/mmcblk0p2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You are unlikely to get a definitive answer because none of us use [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697). (Those who want multi OS use [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md)
.)

NOOBS is actually an Operating System installer and boot manager.

You **CAN NOT** "boot in recovery mode while holding SHIFT key" - you need to **PRESS** SHIFT during the brief period it flashes a message.

It is unclear what you are actually asking; it is simple to detect keypress in a program. If you want a more precise answer about how NOOBS does this you will have to study the code (which is readily available).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the information :-) Can you please suggest some resources where i can find readily available code?

Comment: It is readily found by looking at the Documentation on the Foundation website 
 https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md  or https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs