# Raspberry PI 0 W

Tags: hdmi

I have embedded Raspbian OS in SD card and I have put it in the Raspberry PI 0 W using Noobs method, But if i connect it to lap or some HDMI display via HDMI cable, I am not getting the display Raspberry PI is not getting detected.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "embedded Raspbian OS in SD card", but I strongly suggest you avoid [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) (like the vast bulk of us) and follow the [Foundation Guidelines](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems)

Comment: if by lap you mean laptop that won't work the laptop's HDMI is an output. Also, you need to connect the HDMI cable to the monitor before powering up the Pi.

Answer (score 2):

You should find a friend who is more knowledgeable than you wrt computer technology - or perhaps consider hiring someone to help you. Randomly connecting physical ports between computers may destroy your hardware.

The steps are not difficult, but you should **read** before proceeding.

#### [Start here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/)

Download the OS image you need & *flash* it to your SD card. **Read & Follow** the instructions.

#### Know where the [Documntation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/) is located.

#### Find the applicable documentation

- [This may be helpful](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/setup/)
- [Learn how to connect a monitor](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/setup/monitor-connection.md)
- [Read up on related topics](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/pathways/getting-started-with-raspberry-pi)

#### And please know this:

We are not here to [*spoon-feed*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/spoon-feed) you. We expect that you will put some effort into resolving your problem/question **before** you post questions.