# Install RPi OS from a zip file (No image)

Tags: pi-4, noobs

I have a new RPi 4 and I have installed NOOBS from a zip due to the fact that I cannot install software on my computer as it is loaned from my school (i.e. image writing software)

However, once plugged in to a power source, there is just a singular red light and the green light flashes once really quickly.

I read an article online (https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/raspberry-pi-wont-boot-fix/) which said that if the OS was not supported there would only be a red light and no green light, so I wondered if there was any way to install the latest RPi OS version from a zip file rather than an image?

(I tested my download of NOOBS on a RPi Model B [https://socialcompare.com/en/review/raspberry-pi-model-b] and it worked)

Comment: You might download a portable disk imager (Pi foundation refers a.o. to https://www.upswift.io/imgflasher) and use that if you're on Win10. No need for a real install and you can remove it after use.

Comment: Why do you want to use NOOBS? Many of the problems I've seen on the Raspi are caused directly by NOOBS. SD cards are usually readily available and relatively inexpensive.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the actual question - the only ways to install an OS without an installer are NOOBS or PINN, which are OS installer/boot managers. Few (if any) experienced users on this site use NOOBS, and even on the Foundation site it is discouraged.

If you do want to pursue this I believe [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) is still available, and should run on Pi4 - obviously I haven't tried this.

Many of the NOOBS disks supplied by vendors are obsolete.

A better (and more capable and flexible) option is [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md)

NOTE to use either of these you **NEED** a screen and keyboard

It is possible to install an (uncompressed) image using `dd` which is ubiquitous on Linux and Unix based OS (including macOS)

If you have another Pi and a SD adapter you can install *Raspberry Pi Imager* on the Pi (assuming you have sufficient space for the image).

Comment: Both of NOOBS and PINN worked on the RPi-B but not on the RPi-4. I also tested my micro sd (used for RPI-4) in an SD adapter in the RPi-B and that didn't seem to work either. It may just be an issue with my SD card? Is there any storage size limits that I possibly missed out on?