# dual boot menu with raspbian / librelec not showing anymore

Tags: raspbian, noobs, libreelec

I have a RPI 4 with both Raspbian and Libre elec.

I went 2 monthes in vacation, and now I am coming back, system is only booting on librelec, I cannot find a way to boot on raspbian.

Is there a way to recover dual boot menu ?

I tried to press shift when colors appear on screen, but it stucked.

Comment: Dual boot is not a standard option. How did you set it up?

Comment: With noobs, just install 2 os and it will display a boot menu

Comment: This is the last place you should look for advice on [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) no one uses it, even the Foundation now hides it. Try https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/, but even there it is discouraged. https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md#troubleshooting may help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same situation. In previous versions of Noobs you could install more than one OS. I still have a Pi that is set up like this. If more than one OS was installed you got a prompt to choose. On my Pi 4 this happened for a while then disappeared but working arrow keys during boot up let me switch blind - just guessing key presses with no prompt. I had to switch to PINN, and my MicroSD card was not big enough for two systems, so I just had switch cards. It all seems much more stable now. I think PINN with a large card is the new way to go, even though you can still find info out there on Noobs in places.