# What am I missing in regards to "Raspberry Pi Imager"?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-imager

Today, I went to my bookmark for Raspberry Pi OS to see if there were any new updates. There were.

The horribly-named "NOOBS" installation utility had been renamed into the much less insulting "Raspberry Pi Imager", and I got very excited since it promised to allow simple setup of SSH "and more" in a sleek GUI utility.

I downloaded and installed it, inserted my RPI (v1) SD flash card into my PC and ran it. I picked the default choice (after reviewing the others) and let it write it. (I assume that it must have downloaded the ISO at the same time as it was writing it, because the small installer couldn't possibly contain that huge ISO.)

But... then it was finished. And that's it. No questions about SSH or anything else. I naively hoped that it would ask me if I want full disk encryption, but it asked nothing whatsoever, nor did it offer me to change anything after the writing was done. It just told me to remove the card and put it into my RPI and start using it.

Huh? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The options menu is hidden by default. You need to type <kbd>ctrl shift X</kbd>.

This blog [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-imager-update/) has some additional details about telemetry, and this [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-imager-update-to-v1-6/) has the details about the submenu.

Comment: At first, I assumed that this was a bad joke. But I still tried it, and you're right... They actually went out of their way to HIDE the whole point of the program: to make it easy and not cryptic to set it up... Wow. I'm speechless. And what do I find in the very bottom of that hidden menu? A checked-by-default "Enable telemetry"... What's that all about? Is that the reason why they hid all the options? None of this makes any sense.

Comment: @PB I updated my answer to link to the blog posts that discuss the options menu and telemetry.

Answer (score 3):

"What am I missing?" - reading the [Raspberry Pi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-imager-update-to-v1-6/) Documentation.

Admittedly this is not easy to find, and the advanced options are "hidden", but these do require some expertise to use.

PS Raspberry Pi Imager has ABSOLUTELY nothing to do with [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) which is one of the worst ideas ever conceived.

Comment: It seems that "having nothing to do with..." does not mean that they (RPi Imager & NOOBS) have nothing in common.