# Just got a raspberry pi 4b, it will show bootloader with no SD card in. If I try and insert an SD card the screen flashes. First time booting

Tags: boot, sd-card, screen

This is my first raspberry pi and I've been trying for 4 hours to get it to turn on and I'm starting to think it's defective. I can't find anyone in the internet having the exact same problem as me. I don't want to have to return it and wait for a new one, I was excited to spend the weekend playing with it, but I'm worried I might have to. I'm bummed this is how it's turned out so far.

It will show the bootloader just fine so HDMI works, I tried 2 different SD cards (one was included and preloaded with noobs, but that wouldn't boot either, just flashing screen), I tried 2 different power cables, I tried 4 different OS versions using the raspberry pi imager to write them onto the SD card.

I've tried booting from both the USB port and the SD card reader, so that rules out broken SD card slot.

ACT light blinks, but not in a steady pattern apparently as its supposed to. I did have a separate 7" monitor, was wondering if that was the issue, so connected it to one of my desktop monitors, which didn't receive any signal at all. I've tried everything over the last 4 hours and cannot find a solution. Apparently no one on the internet has had exactly this issue. None of the fixes for similar issues, like black screen are working for me either.

I tried the recovery option on the imager, and it showed the green square as expected. Still, no successful boot to an OS. I don't know what else to do. I'm pretty sure it's dead.

Comment: You mention several times "as it should" without mention HOW it is acting, so when it lacks data/and verifiable data it is IMPOSSIBLE to give you any help, its just going to be a guessing game! Please add What you have done with verifiable data like links or description of what you have done and describe the result!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do you make your sd cards?

Answer (score 0):

[NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) is (and always has been) a kludge.

Even the Foundation has given up on it, and it is now hidden.
It hasn't been updated for over a year.

The **recommended** method to install Raspberry Pi OS is described https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/getting-started.html#installing-the-operating-system

It **IS** possible to boot from the USB port, but not recommended for a beginner, although the web site describes how.

You should seek a refund for the obsolete overpriced SD Card - most responsible vendors should supply Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: Yeah I ended up using the raspberry pi imager I downloaded from the website. I just found out what it was. The HDMI that came with the 7" display was faulty. I did get a signal on my desktop monitor after another attempt. And the boot loader had a bunch of red lines. So I switched to the HDMI provided with the raspberry pi and it worked. I never would've guessed because the 7" screen displayed the boot loader with no issues.