# python script can only work in geany not in terminal@@

Tags: pi-3, python

i have one python script send message to my phone using pywhatkit

it can run flawlessly on geany IDE.but when i invoke from terminal like sudo python3   /home/pi/Desktop/pyf/whatsappsend.py it run in terminal but it doesn't open whatsapp web and send message.

the script as follow

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf_8 -*-
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import time

from time import strftime,localtime
from time import strftime,gmtime 

while True:
    print('running')
    
    dt_gmt = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime())
 
    print(dt_gmt) 
    time_only = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly("+65XXXXXXX", str("hello")+str(dt_gmt), 30, True, 10)
    time.sleep(60)
```

pls help me how to make it run on terminal as i want to put in on crontab later on.

Thanks in advance.

Myo

Comment: It is unclear what OS you are using and you haven't listed any diagnostics.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"

it should be new.i just download noobs yesterday

Comment: Don't put detail in comments - edit your post.

Comment: [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) is unsupported. It is almost impossible to find, hasn't been updated for a year, and wouldn't support Bullseye.

Comment: Why are you trying to run it with sudo? Use `python3 /home/pi/Desktop/pyf/whatsappsend.py` with no sudo and see how that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to run python3 use:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

`#!/usr/bin/env python` is python2 in most OS.

It may not make any difference in Bullseye, but it still doesn't hurt to do it properly.

Why are you using `sudo`. If the code runs it is almost certainly unnecessary.

Comment: now it get another error without sudo is permission denied
    with open("PyWhatKit_DB.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'PyWhatKit_DB.txt'

Comment: permission problem fixed by chmod to that txt file .ok again .thanks mr milliways.