# Help loading backup in new rpi. It does not work

Tags: pi-4, bootloader, firmware

I am new here and this is my first question. If it is out of place I apologize, and please move it to where it belongs.

First of all I will put you in background:
In my building automation and control company a few years ago it was decided to acquire several Raspbery Pi 4 model B to create a solution to a problem (it was something "as simple" as displaying on a screen the temperature and humidity of the building read through a BACnet).

The project was delivered and was working properly for several years. The person who developed it is no longer with us and did not leave any documents or manuals to replicate the project.
We keep a copy of the complete image of the SD card, and on some occasions, when some RPI has failed, it has helped us to buy another one, load the image and run.

So far so good, the problem comes when 1 month ago, one of the RPI breaks showing the error "CMA: Failed to reserve 256 MiB". Since we do not handle this issue well, to save time, we decided to buy a new motherboard and perform the usual procedure by loading a backup.

The problem (attached photo): When loading the usual copy, it always generates errors such as "Missing/empty fixup4rc.dat", "recover4.elf is not compatible" and "This board requires newer software", the solutions I have found are how to update the recover and start files to more recent versions have not given any results.

[image]

*Note: I have indications that the system was developed using NOOBS, I don't know if this has any influence.

Can you help me reset my system? Could it be the Bootloader version? Can you downgrade the bootloader?

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to boot something that's over three years old. The time to upgrade is now.

Comment: We are working on a new solution.
But in the meantime, can I update/upgrade one of the working rpi and make the updated system exportable to the new board? Or, on the other hand, when updating one of the old ones it will stop working?

Comment: It is generally better here to not use an image, but to use text instead. This will be more readable, especially to those of us whose eyes are a bit worn out.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using an old Pi (which model?) and purchased a new model (which?) it probably won't work as there have been hardware changes.

If you were using [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) it is not upgradeable as this has been abandoned for years and AFAIK there never was a version for Pi4. (It is hard to believe any competent designer would use NOOBS.)

Was the original a Pi4 (if so which version)?

What is "the usual procedure"?

When was "a few years ago"?

Without documentation your best option would be to give your project specification to a new designer (and insist on full documentation).

Comment: Good morning @Milivías, sorry, I was on my days off.

The programs were developed in 2020. I am not 100% sure that they have been developed on NOOBS other than that there is an "INSTRUCTIONS-README.txt" inside the recovery folder that talks about how to mount NOOBS.

The original Rpi were Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.

The new Rpi purchased is a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.

With the usual procedure, I mean uploading a backup copy, we have done this on other occasions without a problem.

Don't you think there is a way to restore the project?

Comment: Are there now two machines with the same address?